# Joining multiple issue

Tags: mysql

I am really having trouble joining mulitple tables in a working query.

There are 5 different tables:

1. Event storing: eventid, staffnumber, date, start and end date..
2. Event_overview storing: eventid, clientid..
3. Rates storing: clientid, rateswaiter, rateschef, ratesteamleader..
4. staff: staffid, firstname, lastname..
5. salary: staffid, salary

I want to create one table giving me the result for all events grouped by staffid indicating the total number of hours they worked per event, the rate according to their role per hour and multiplied by the number of hours they worked, the salary, salary*hours

I have started with two different tables which work perfectly on their own.

```
Select event.staffid, staff.firstname,   
staff.lastname, salary.wage, evento.clientid,
event.date, TIMEDIFF( hours, pause ) AS Total, event.role
from event
inner join evento on event.eventid=evento.eventid
inner join salary on event.staffid=salary.staffid
inner join staff on event.staffid=staff.staffid
```

The second query

```
SELECT event.clientid
FROM evento
JOIN rates ON evento.clientid = rates.clientid
group by evento.clientid
```

Later I want need to decide which rate to select based on the role of the staff member

```
   CASE WHEN Position = 'Teamleader'
   THEN (Teamleader)
   WHEN Position = 'waiter'
    THEN (waiter)
   WHEN Position = 'chef'
       THEN (chef)
  ELSE '0'
  END AS revenue
```

I want to have those information in one table so I can start mulitpliying and summing up per staff member and using above queries as subqueries.

Hope someone can help me. 
thanks in advance,

Comment: What problem are you having? The only error I see is that you should be using `rateTeamleader`, `rateWaiter`, and `rateChef`. You'd be more extendable if you had a table that related position names to rates, then you could join with this table on position instead of using a CASE statement.

Comment: Well how do I join those two tables? by cross join?

Comment: What two tables? These are queries, not tables. You can join them as subqueries if you need to. Or you can use the CASE statement as part of an expression, to multiply by the hours after joining.

Comment: It's not clear what you want as a final result. Post some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: sorry yes of course queries. But as you might see on my comment there are two select queries and I would like to join. I did this with a where clause where evento.clientid in (SELECT event.clientid....but when I was inserting the case statement mysql didn't know the colum rateTeamleader etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you want:

```
Select event.staffid, staff.firstname,   
       staff.lastname, salary.wage, evento.clientid,
       event.date, TIMEDIFF( hours, pause ) AS Total, event.role,
       TIMEDIFF(hours, pause) *
         case position 
              when 'Teamleader' then rateteamleader
              when 'waiter' then ratewaiter
              when 'chef' then ratechef
         end TotalSalary 
from event
inner join evento on event.eventid=evento.eventid
inner join salary on event.staffid=salary.staffid
inner join staff on event.staffid=staff.staffid
inner join rates on evento.clientid = rates.clientid
```

It would be better if you normalized the `rates` table, with columns: `clientid`, `position`, `rate`. Then the join would be:

```
inner join rates on evento.clientid = rates.clientid and staff.position = rates.position
```

and you would just do `TIMEDIFF(house, pause) * rate` to get `TotalSalary`.

Comment: I normalized the rate table and then took your recommendation for the query. Thank you that was really a great help and I am happy that I was able to resolve this. :-)